# Why output is different between to shell and to a file

Tags: c, bash, unix, fork

Consider the following program.

```
main() {  
  printf("hello\n");  
  if(fork()==0)  
    printf("world\n");  
  exit(0);  
}
```

Compiling this program using `./a.out` gives the following Output:

```
hello  
world
```

compiling this program using `./a.out > output` gives the output in the file called 'output' and appears to be like this:

```
hello  
hello  
world
```

Why is this so?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Because when you output to shell `stdout` is usually line buffered, while when you write to a file, it's usually full buffered.

After `fork()`, the child process will inherit the buffer, when you output to shell, the buffer is empty because of the new line `\n`, but when you output to a file, the buffer still contains the content, and will be in both the parent and child's output buffer, that's why `hello` is seen twice.

You can try it like this:

```
int main() {  
  printf("hello");    //Notice here without "\n"
  if(fork()==0)  
    printf("world\n");  
  exit(0);  
}
```

You will likely see `hello` twice when output to shell as well.

Answer (score 3):

This answer after Yu Hao 's answer . He already explain a lot .

```
main() {  
  printf("hello\n");  
  fflush(stdout);//flush the buffer
  if(fork()==0)  
    printf("world\n");  
  exit(0);  
}
```

Then you can get the right output.